# C++ uni task to show the cheapest ticket for the farthest city

Tags: c++

I am a newcomer cs student, I have a uni task
[shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB0It.png)

> ### Plane ticket to go far far away
>
> A travel agency stores the prices of the plane tickets to cities being different distances away.
>
> Write a program that gives the price of the plane ticket to the farthest city.
>
> ### Input
>
> The first line of the *standard input* contains the count of cities `(1 <= N <= 100)`. The next `N` lines contain the distance of a city `(1 <= D <= 20 000)` and the price of the plane ticket `(1 <= P <= 2 000 000)` each.
>
> ### Output
>
> The first line of the *standard output* should contain the price of the plane ticket to the farthest city (if there is more than one solution, you should give the cheapest).
>
> ### Example
>
> ```
> Input                    Output
> 6                        30000
> 50 30000
> 1900 200000
> 2000 150000
> 900 38000
> 600 150000
> 2100 30000
> ```

I can solve the test case attached, but I can't code the part of **"(if there is more than one solution, you should give the cheapest)."**

the test case that doesn't work is  as following

```
100
7000 703810
14000 1404764
8000 801176
5000 500424
2000 203546
3000 302438
14000 1399785
10000 1001770
11000 1101070
18000 1802146
19000 1899694
5000 499560
13000 1304064
6000 596372
2000 197292
15000 1503815
7000 704044
8000 801457
12000 1198246
16000 1600197
13000 1295000
17000 1698118
6000 599254
16000 1603853
5000 501798
19000 1899561
14000 1399834
5000 502887
19000 1897294
15000 1503802
6000 598136
5000 504574
11000 1099717
2000 202115
5000 496536
9000 902304
8000 801462
10000 997148
6000 596864
12000 1203075
17000 1702470
4000 401748
11000 1097768
4000 396749
14000 1402044
9000 899631
12000 1203404
5000 497048
4000 396649
10000 996248
8000 802220
18000 1795304
15000 1502469
15000 1495925
18000 1797174
3000 302492
11000 1102316
12000 1195456
19000 1897091
7000 697869
6000 601772
3000 295630
2000 200556
18000 1795092
14000 1403330
16000 1604843
7000 702034
12000 1196816
3000 300123
10000 1000804
19000 1902875
17000 1701064
8000 797184
19000 1899551
6000 603788
19000 1899922
18000 1802155
16000 1599861
13000 1302085
17000 1699981
7000 703445
17000 1696943
13000 1302733
2000 204742
8000 803623
4000 402804
19000 1904850
10000 1002535
10000 995040
13000 1297694
8000 799104
4000 399282
16000 1597978
5000 499011
11000 1096206
6000 604806
3000 299061
17000 1700692
19000 1898436
19000 1902888
```

and the output `1897091`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n_cities = 0;
    cin >> n_cities;
    while (!(n_cities <= 100 && n_cities >= 1))
    {
        cin >> n_cities;
    }

    int d[n_cities], i;
    int p[n_cities];
    for (i = 0; i < n_cities; i++)
    {
        cin >> d[i] >> p[i];
        while (!(d[i] >= 1 && d[i] <= 20000 && p[i] <= 2000000 && p[i] >= 1))
        {
            cin >> d[i] >> p[i];
        }
    }

    int farthest = 0;
    int index = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n_cities; i++)
    {
        if (farthest < d[i])
            farthest = d[i];
        index = i;
    }
    //The first line of the standard output should contain the price of the plane ticket to the
    //farthest city(if there is more than one solution, you should give the cheapest).

    //cheapest
    int cheapest = p[index];
    int cheap_p[n_cities], j = 0, cnt = 0;
    for (j = 0; i < n_cities; j++)
    {
        if (farthest == d[j])
        {
            cheap_p[j] = p[j];
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < cnt; k++)
    {
        if (cheapest < cheap_p[k])
            cheapest = cheap_p[k];
    }

    cout << "cheapest normal" << cheapest;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What steps have you taken to try and debug this? Does it work on other test cases where there are duplicate distances?

Comment: No, it does not work in case of duplicated distances,

Comment: I modified the code int he question, debugged it and changed the last if condition, but still, the same problem occurs

Comment: For effective debugging you probably want to simplify the example data so that the answer is easy to debug.

Comment: This `int d[n_cities]` is incorrect and doesn't even compile. The size parameter of a C-style array declaration must be a constant value. There are other red flags in the code as well. Have you been taught about the STL?

Comment: For the cheapest part you don't need an array. Just find the minimum p[i] when d[i] == farthest. You can do that in a single loop after you find the farthest . You may even be able to do this in the loop where you find the farthest. If a new farthest is found reset the cheapest to the current value. If the same distance is found again compare the cost to the cheapest and set cheapest to be the minimum of the 2 costs.

Comment: I'm not sure what you've been taught so far in your course and what kinds of data structures are allowed for this assignment. Intuitively, you could store the data in a struct (structured variable), an arbitrary class, a map, etc. that would allow you to easily solve the problem.

Comment: thanks guys, i have solved it from your advice, I used less loops and drescherjim told me, and it worked

Comment: @Boruv Post your solution as an answer :)

Comment: Note that [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (VLAs) do not exist in the C++ language as defined by the ISO C++ standard. Therefore, `int d[n_cities]` will not work on many C++ compilers. Some compilers may support VLAs as an extension to the C++ language, but if you use them, you will be sacrificing portability, as your code will only work on some compilers and not on others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you indicated in the comments that you already solved it, for posterity's sake, here's how I would solve the problem using Modern C++. The algorithms header makes the problem trivial:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

int main() {
    //Get the number of cities.
    const int n_cities = []() {
        std::cout << "Count: ";
        int n{1};
        for(;;) {
            if(std::cin >> n) {
                while(!(n <= 100 && n >= 1))
                {
                    std::cout << "\nNumber of cities out of range.\nCount: ";
                    std::cin >> n;
                }
                break;
            } else {
                std::cout << "\nNot a number\nCount: ";
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore((std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max)(), '\n');
            }
        }
        return n;
    }(); //Immediately Invoked Initializing Lambda

    //Load the distances and prices.
    const std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> tickets = [](int n) {
        std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> result{};
        result.resize(n);
        for(auto& ticket : result) {
            for(;;) {
                if(std::cin >> ticket.first >> ticket.second) {
                    while(!(ticket.first >= 1 && ticket.first <= 20000 && ticket.second <= 2000000 && ticket.second >= 1))
                    {
                        std::cin >> ticket.first >> ticket.second;
                    }
                    break;
                } else {
                    std::cout << "\nNot a number. Enter Distance and Price: ";
                    std::cin.clear();
                    std::cin.ignore((std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max)(), '\n');
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }(n_cities); //Immediately Invoked Initializing Lambda

    //Find the smallest element by furthest distance, then cheapest price.
    const auto best_ticket = std::min_element(std::cbegin(tickets), std::cend(tickets), [](const auto& a, const auto& b)->bool {
        if(a.first > b.first) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if(a.first == b.first) {
                if(a.second < b.second) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    std::cout << "Best ticket: " << (*best_ticket).second;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was working on a similar alternative implementation, but I can see that you beat me to it!

Comment: Thanks a lot Casey, I appreciate your efforts writing the code, while it is really hard for me to understand, I suppose because I have just started programming and I don't have that much of experiance